# How to change permissions of Wordpress and/or apache on macOS securely?

Tags: php, wordpress, macos, apache

I have encountered a problem when trying to add an image to WordPress:

> "Unable to create directory wp-content/uploads/2017/05. Is its parent directory writable by the server?".

Thing is that I installed WordPress locally, without MAMP. Root for Apache is `/Library/WebServer`, port is `80`.

Already tried adding `define( 'UPLOADS', 'wp-content/uploads' );` to `wp-config.php`, but it didn't work. According to this, I assume that problems are with permissions of WordPress to `/Library/WebServer`.

Anyone knows how to change this permissions securely?

Answer (score 0):

Use command line tools.

Run the following commands to change the permission of the wordpress folder.

```
find yourwordpressfolder -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;
find yourwordpressfolder -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;
```

On mac you can find terminal which is used as command line tool.

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work.
I first typed wordpress folder directory to yourwordpressfolder, that didn't work, and then just because of curiosity typed uploads directory to yourwordpressfolder. Nothing of written above solved the problem :C